# The point of ValueConversionAttribute class?

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

What is the point of this attribute? After adding it I still need to make a cast on value object.

```
[ValueConversion(sourceType: typeof(double), targetType: typeof(string))]
public class SpeedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var speed = (double)value;
```

Is it only for code readability? 
Because when I change a binding's path to a String in xaml, Visual Studio doesn't give a warning about incorrect type and exception is thrown only when casting, so it doesn't mean a thing even in early error catching while compiling.
I also can change a cast to string and no warning is thrown despite it conflicting with this Attribute.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can potentially use the `ValueConversionAttribute` to determine what types are involved in the converters, and use that information usefully.
Look at [Piping Value Converters in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15061/Piping-Value-Converters-in-WPF) as an excellent example for the use of `ValueConversionAttribute`.

The example shows how multiple converter classes can be chained, and ValueConversion can be used to pass type info to next converter in line.

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( string ), typeof( ProcessingState ) )]
public class IntegerStringToProcessingStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
 object IValueConverter.Convert( 
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
 {
  int state;
  bool numeric = Int32.TryParse( value as string, out state );
  Debug.Assert( numeric, "value should be a String which contains a number" );
  Debug.Assert( targetType.IsAssignableFrom( typeof( ProcessingState ) ), 
    "targetType should be ProcessingState" ); 

  switch( state )
  {
   case -1:
    return ProcessingState.Complete; 
   case 0:
    return ProcessingState.Pending; 
   case +1:
    return ProcessingState.Active;
  }
  return ProcessingState.Unknown;
 } 

 object IValueConverter.ConvertBack( 
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
 {
  throw new NotSupportedException( "ConvertBack not supported." );
 }
}
// *************************************************************
[ValueConversion( typeof( ProcessingState ), typeof( Color ) )]
public class ProcessingStateToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
 object IValueConverter.Convert( 
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
 {
  Debug.Assert(value is ProcessingState, "value should be a ProcessingState");
  Debug.Assert( targetType == typeof( Color ), "targetType should be Color" );

  switch( (ProcessingState)value )
  {
   case ProcessingState.Pending:
    return Colors.Red; 
   case ProcessingState.Complete:
    return Colors.Gold; 
   case ProcessingState.Active:
    return Colors.Green;
  }
  return Colors.Transparent;
 } 

 object IValueConverter.ConvertBack( 
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
 {
  throw new NotSupportedException( "ConvertBack not supported." );
 }
} 

object IValueConverter.Convert( 
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
{
 object output = value; 
 for( int i = 0; i < this.Converters.Count; ++i )
 {
  IValueConverter converter = this.Converters[i];
  Type currentTargetType = this.GetTargetType( i, targetType, true );
  output = converter.Convert( output, currentTargetType, parameter, culture );

  // If the converter returns 'DoNothing' 
  // then the binding operation should terminate.
  if( output == Binding.DoNothing )
   break;
 } 
 return output;
}
//***********Usage in XAML*************
    <!-- Converts the Status attribute text to a Color -->
    <local:ValueConverterGroup x:Key="statusForegroundGroup">
          <local:IntegerStringToProcessingStateConverter  />
          <local:ProcessingStateToColorConverter />
    </local:ValueConverterGroup>
```

Comment: IMHO, this should be the answer because it shows the programmatic need/usage of the attribute.  Great find.

Answer (score 16):

It is just an annotation.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

> When implementing the IValueConverter interface, it is a good practice to decorate the implementation with a **ValueConversionAttribute** attribute to indicate to development tools the data types involved in the conversion

I do not know what the "development tools" would do with that information...

Comment: It's easier to write such information in comments. Maybe it is used for auto generating documentation?

Comment: Uh-huh... Well atleast I've got a purpose in my life - write a Visual Studio add-in to make use of this attribute.

Comment: If that text originally came from that linked page, then it has since been changed. The description now merely states '**Represents an attribute that allows the author of a value converter to specify the data types involved in the implementation of the converter**'. Even less helpful now!

Comment: @Sheridan: Indeed. That was from the examples section of version 4 (still accessible via the `Other Versions` drop-down).

Comment: Ahh, you are so right. It seems bizarre that they would remove the examples section from the latest page.