# How to display a text without the whitespaces in Xaml textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I get an input from a different view model, and i need to show it in another window without the white spaces inserted. But it should not replace the original text. I need the white spaces removed only when displayed

Comment: Are you databinding to the model property or are you setting it via `.Text = `?

Comment: Consider using Value Converter.

Comment: @kennyzx the value converter will change the original text. It there any other way we can solve in the Xaml code level. Without converting?

Comment: @Gethma Yes to which question?

Comment: Are you databinding to the model property or are you setting it via .Text = ? Yes i do @johanP

Comment: @Gethma if it is just for display, then one-way binding with a converter can do the trick. For example, if the property in the viewmodel is “Hello World”, you can bind to the property and display “HelloWorld” in the View with a value converter that removes the white spaces out of the original string. And since it’s one way binding you don’t have to worry that the View modifies the property in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need [`Converter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) to trim your text like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

[ValueConversion( typeof( string ), typeof( string ) )]
public class NoWhiteSpaceTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if ( ( value is string ) == false )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "value should be string type" );
        }

        string returnValue = ( value as string );

        return returnValue != null ? returnValue.Trim() : returnValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use converter with text binding in `xaml` like this:

```
<Windows.Resources>         
     <converter:NoWhiteSpaceTextConverter x:Key="noWhiteSpaceTextConverter"></converter:NoWhiteSpaceTextConverter>            
</Windows.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding YourTextWithSpaces, Converter={StaticResource noWhiteSpaceTextConverter}}" />
```

Comment: [ValueConversion( typeof( string ), typeof( string ) )] what does this line mean?

Comment: It is optional but good practice to understand converter better: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628979/2106315